# Does a "VS 10 x64" program work well on x86 OSs?

Tags: visual-studio, x86

I would like to start programming using **Visual Studio 10 (64 bit)** but I don't know : Does a **VS 64 bit** program work well on **32 bit** Operating system?

*I'm sorry if it is an asked question. I didn't find that.*

Comment: you can run a 32bit app on 64bit OS, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@In silico is correct that it will work, but [there is no 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx).

Visual Studio will run on x86 and x64 systems, and is capable of generating 32-bit and 64-bit programs regardless of the OS platform.  There is also an "Any CPU" build option that will allow the same executable to run on both x86 and x64 systems, but there may be some cases where that is not an option for you.

Answer (score 4):

No. 64-bit programs cannot run on a 32-bit machine. So 64-bit versions of Visual Studio (if such a thing exists) will not run on a 32-bit machine. On the other hand, you can run 32-bit programs on 64-bit machines. On Windows this is achieved via the [WoW64 subsystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64).

But the Visual Studio compilers are more than capable of producing executables for both 32-bit platforms and 64-bit platforms, even if the compilers themselves run on a different architecture. These are called [cross compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

In Visual Studio a program compiled for "x86" is a 32-bit program and a program compiled for "x64" is a 64-bit program (specifically, an [x86-64 program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)). Thus, an "x64" program will not run on a 32-bit machine (or any machine that's not x86-64 compatible).